# My Enum is getting converted to an empty string and struct converted to an empty dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a model defined as this

```
public class SportEvent
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string EventId { get; set; }
        public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public DateTime GameTime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public Sports Sport { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public SportLeagueStruct League { get; set; }
...
    }
```

`Sports` is a standard enum and `SportLeagueStruct` is a struct. Both of these values are being sent but when added to the database, the `Sport` value gets converted into an empty string and the `League` value gets converted to an empty dictionary.  My `SportLeagueStruct` struct has a property called `name` that I want to be considered as its string value in the `SportEvent` class and for `Sports` I just want the string value of the enum.  How would I implement this?

```
public struct SportLeagueStruct
    {
        public string name;
        public string espnName;
        public Sports sport;

        public SportLeagueStruct(string name, string espnName, Sports sport)
        {

            this.name = name;
            this.espnName = espnName;
            this.sport = sport;
        }
    }
```

```
public enum Sports
    {
        BASEBALL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but by far the simplest is to declare your enum and structs as strings as you intend to. Then you just have to convert from string to enum/struct yourself. Declaration:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string Sport { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string League { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would prefer to keep the actual types as `Sports` and `SportLeagueStruct` , is it possible while keeping them as there actual types?

Comment: You can add those as tables but then they have to be entities (class) and not struct